# deploying a node.js on a new domain

Tags: node.js, domain-name

I have a server that runs different websites on different ports. All of them (but one) are Apache servers and thanks to webmin, I managed to have, for instance, example.com point to 123.123.123.123:80 and example.fr to 123.123.123.123:8000, somehow automatically

I am now running a nodejs server on the same machine, so the 80, 8000, and many other ports are already taken. My nodejs listens on 8008. I have another domain name, say example.org, and I want it to point to my nodejs website, but I simply don't know how to do that! I have updated the DNS and everything is pointing to 123.123.123.123 (my server's IP). I want to avoid using an ugly example.org:8008/ for everything on this node server. How can I make it point implicitly to the 8008 port?? I must add that I cannot afford to take down the apache servers ;)

Comment: You want DNS to point to the 8008 not 80... Am I understanding this right? If so, no-can-do. DNS can't do that. You can probably do a redirect in Apache to the :8008 site - so hitting one domain will go to this odd port server. Google "redirect Apache domain odd port"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS only provides name to ip address mapping. It cannot handle ports. What you can do instead is to set up a proxy server listening on port 80. The proxy server can then return data based on the host header.

Your best option is to just redirect the request from Apache. Otherwise you can use a reverse proxy like Nginx. Also, you can write a lightweight proxy in node... check out [this page](http://www.catonmat.net/http-proxy-in-nodejs/)